# MySQL getting the X byte in a string

Tags: mysql, string, type-conversion, byte

I have a database that I'm trying to extract some data out of, we are converting a customer to our system from another, and the source database has a field called `line` which is a varchar.

However the field does not contain just text, the 1st x bytes of the string are status codes which are just bytes, so as an example a line may read `Â foo` which when reading in a hex editor is `03 C2 A0 66 6F 6F`

I'm trying in MySQL to run a query to show what is at the say the 3rd byte, however I'm not getting the correct resutls. I suspect that MySQL is treating the characters as UTF-8 and when I substring i'm getting a two byte character

What I have tried a couple of things the first was `HEX(ASCII(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(line USING utf8mb4), 3, 1)))`.  I have also tried replacing the '''CONVERT(line USING utf8mb4)''' with '''CONVERT(line, BINARY) ''' this yeilds the same results.

When I read the 1st character I get back 03, I read the second character I get C2, when I try the 3rd character I get back 0 instead of A0.

I have just tried copying the output from that field and having it as a string literal and that works fine, it is only when it being read from the database.

This works

`HEX(ASCII(SUBSTRING(CONVERT('Â ', BINARY),3, 1)))`  -- The string is the following values in hex 03C2A0

This doesn't work

`HEX(ASCII(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(line, BINARY),1, 1)))`   -- line contains the same string as the above example.

Any suggestions into what will work? I ideally need to get this working as a query rather than any post manipulation.

Thanks
Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure this out a couple of days later. I did think I posted the solution to my own question.

It was as simple as converting the line data into the utf8mb4 then into binary, this then gives me access to each byte in the line.

`HEX(ASCII(substring(CONVERT(CONVERT(line using utf8mb4), BINARY),4,1)))`

Had to use both, which is what I didn't see at first.

I hope this may help someone in the future.

Cheers.